# Resize div based on height of another div

Tags: jquery, css, resize

I'm currently working on something similar that was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131770/jquery-dynamically-resize-div-based-on-height-of-another-div).
But for some reason I cannot get it to work when the viewport/browser window is resized. Not too sure if there is something with my CSS or if it's something else.

Here's the code that I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.more').hide();

$('.link').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.more').slideToggle();
}).toggle(function() {
    $(this).children("span").text("[-]");
}, function() {
    $(this).children("span").text("[+]");
    return false;
});
var maxHeight = 0;
$('div.simultaneously').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = $(this).height();
    }
});
$('div.simultaneously').height(maxHeight);
});​
```

I'm trying to get the left column (lft-col) to match the height of the hidden div when it slides down. Overall I want the left column div to have the full height of the browser if the viewport is resized. And if the hidden div is slid down, if there is any scroll, I want the left column div to match the height of the right column div is revealed.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sLVsR/5/

If anyone has a different way to approach this, I am all for it as well.

Comment: If you want to have the `div` resize on browser/viewport change, use [.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: I'm working from of the similar post, but I'm not sure if the toggleSlide is causing it not to function the same way or if there is another way to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: @kei - so use .resize instead of .height?

Comment: You should also add a stop to your "Read more", if you click contineously it doesn't stop. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having re-read your question, I've made a few changes to your code

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("div.lft-col").height($(window).height()-20); //I've put in -20 just so you can see the div shadow

    $('.more').hide();

    $('.link')
        .click(function() {
            $more = $(this).next('.more');
            $more.slideToggle('slow', function() {
                if ($more.is(":visible"))
                    $("div.lft-col").height($(document).height()-20);
               else
                    $("div.lft-col").height($(window).height()-20);
            });
        })
        .toggle(function() {
            $(this).children("span").text("[-]");
        }, function() {
            $(this).children("span").text("[+]");
            return false;
        });

    $(window).resize(function(){
       $("div.lft-col").height($(document).height()-20);
    });

});​
```

**CSS**

```
#container { 
    /*height: 100%;*/    
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/xfFF9/2/)

Comment: Ahhhhhh, I see. Ok. That makes sense. Yeah, I didn't know if I even need that container ID in there any more anyways. I see it now with it looking for the document and then checking the window element if the other div is not visible. But I will definitely play around with this. I really appreciate it.